# Why WHERE work incorrect

Tags: android, sql

I write

```
Cursor c = db.query("contacts", null, "label <> ?", new String[]{cons.LABEL_SKIP}, null, null, "name");
```

cons.LABEL_SKIP equals Skipped;

I want to select data base lines whose label not equals Skipped, but answer comes empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
Cursor c = db.query("contacts", null, "label != ?", 
                                  new String[] { cons.LABEL_SKIP });
```

Comment: check you table name is it contacts ? and what is the content of cons.LABELSKIP ?

Comment: if i do Cursor c = db.query("contacts", null, "id = ?", new String[]{some_id}, null, null, "name");  It is work good.
Label maybe: null and Skipped

Comment: then your cons.Label_SKIP is empty

Comment: no, he is not empty. Check my comment above, i write "Label maybe: null and Skipped and other"

Comment: do you have a column with the name of label ?

Comment: what is the content of cons.LABEL_SKIP ?

Comment: I write in a question "cons.LABEL_SKIP equals Skipped;"